# Is there a sensible way to use Vue.js to generate a static front-end template, basis of a WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, vue.js

I guess I'll get some flak for even asking, but here we go.

I'm a full-stack web developer, and most of the projects I work in are based on WordPress. I start by developing front end mockups in [CodeKit](https://codekitapp.com/), using Pug, Sass and transpiled JS modules. It works mostly well, but it takes some self discipline and effort to keep things minimally modular, lean and clean.

I have also worked on some Vue.js projects, which I have absolulety loved. I have successfully combined both platforms, using WP as a headless CMS for Vue.js. But many WordPress projects just *require* a regular theme, coded in PHP with monolithic styles and scripts.

I would very much like to be able to code my mockups in Vue and somehow generate a completely static build, much like the one I get with CodeKit (or webpack, gulp, ...). All scripts bundled into a single JS file, all styles in a single CSS file. Then some other dev (or myself) could start building a WP theme from that static mockup.

Vue features I'd like to use:

- .vue component files, with markup, scripts and styles within the same file
- Component slots
- I don't need routing, state store or anything fancy

Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you looked into VuePress? It seems like what you want

Comment: VuePress looks promising, yes. Thanks, @IgorMoraru.